# I have made a photodiode circuit and measured using multimeter - still no change in voltage. What to do?

Tags: photodiode

My photodiode is MTPD1346D-100 (InGaAs PIN photodiode.)

What is the photodiode input voltage?

This is my circuit schematic:

[image]

Comment: Unclear what is connected to J4. Measure what input voltage and where? This circuit doesn't work on the voltage across the photodiode, instead it keeps the voltage **zero** as it is a **transimpedance amplifier**. Then the current though the photodiode is converted into a voltage. Go study "transimpedance amplifier" and how they're used with photo diodes. It helps if you first try to figure out **how a circuit is supposed to work** instead of randomly measuring voltages and complaining they're not changing. The circuit is designed to behave like that!

Comment: J4 is to give input to opamp..using 3 9v batterry ..+9v and -9v is generated for opamp..

Comment: If you need to give "input to the opamp" then why is there a photodiode? Are you trying to use the photodiode in forward mode or reverse mode? What mode would make more sense?

Comment: i am trying to make an optical power meter..it is reverse biased and i gave a -3.9v input to the photodiode and measured the output of opamp using multimetr and it is showing same 6v even if light is incident on it

Comment: @titothomas, what was the light source? How did you focus it onto the photodiode?

Comment: I used a ofc cable light..still no change in voltage

Comment: replace the photodiode with 100,000 ohm resistor to -15 volts. You must read +1.5 volts out, or there is serious circuit/scientist problems.

Comment: is photodiode or opamp must be connected to 15 volts

Answer (score 3):

According to the datasheet, the Rated Breakdown Voltage is 3V.

[image: MTPD1346D-100 Datasheet]

Since the negative input of the amplifier is being "pulled" to 0 at the very start, you might be degrading its performance by overdriving it with -3,5V. Try increasing (reducing) the voltage to something around -2V.

Here some explanation:
http://sphereoptics.de/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/AN-Photodiode-Parameters-and-Characteristics.pdf

The transimpedance amplifier can be tested by replacing the photodiode with a current sink:

[image]

Bear in mind that the output will decrease if the input voltage (V3) is increased since the current sink is being pulled to ground. You can sweep the input voltage and check whether it affects (decrease) the output voltage.

Comment: yesc i have tried -2v..but the output is only 4.2v..no change in voltage after light is incident

Comment: Did you try replacing the photodiode with a current source (NPN will do it) in order to check whether your transimpedance amplifier is working properly?

Comment: how is it.can u give me a diagram or something

Comment: @titothomas see my edited answer.

Comment: @vtolentino, the n-p-n transistor is rather a current sink... but the problem here is that there is no what to sink...

Comment: @Circuitfantasist I amended my answer regarding the description. The rectified output of the op amp is providing the current to be sunk.

Comment: @vtolentino, I meant that there is no exciting voltage in your circuit since, from the one side, the transistor sink is grounded and, from the other side, the op-amp keeps zero voltage at its output. You should insert a voltage source somewhere in the path to make some current flow. .. e.g., by connecting the emitter to  -15 V... or by "lifting" the voltage at the non-inverting input (if the op-amp was single-supplied). Because now one would think the transistor really produces current:)... which is also inspired by its presentation as a current source in textbook illustrations...